# EFI virtual machine on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, uefi

Is it possible to create EFI virtual machine running on Hyper-V? Which Hyper-V version should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyper-V 2012 R2 generation 2 VM environments have UEFI firmware.

See:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282285.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2013/10/24/hyper-v-generation-2-virtual-machines-part-1.aspx